# Failed to Open Stream Error with OAuth token exchange example

Tags: magento2, oauth

I am following the OAuth token exchange example [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html#oauth-example) running on Magento 2.4.1 on MAMP

I created an integration and copied the 4 PHP files at the root of the server. I create an integration and set it with:

Callback URL : http://magento2:8888/endpoint.php
Identity link URL : http://magento2:8888/login.php

Then upon activation it opens a pop up and I click login then immediately see this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught
> OAuth\Common\Http\Exception\TokenResponseException:
> file_get_contents(http://magento2:8888/oauth/token/request): failed to
> open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request in
> /code/MAMP/magento2/vendor/lusitanian/oauth/src/OAuth/Common/Http/Client/StreamClient.php:73
> Stack trace: #0
> /code/MAMP/magento2/vendor/lusitanian/oauth/src/OAuth/OAuth1/Service/AbstractService.php(52):
> OAuth\Common\Http\Client\StreamClient->retrieveResponse(Object(OAuth\Common\Http\Uri\Uri),
> '', Array) #1 /code/MAMP/magento2/checklogin.php(26):
> OAuth\OAuth1\Service\AbstractService->requestRequestToken() #2 {main}
> thrown in
> /code/MAMP/magento2/vendor/lusitanian/oauth/src/OAuth/Common/Http/Client/StreamClient.php
> on line 73

What am I missing??

Answer (score 0):

Issue was that Authorization Header wasnt getting processed correctly by the Apache Server and had to add this to Apache config file:

```
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
```